# How to scrape all <li id=> where all ID has different value?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have been trying for few hours to print out all `<li id =List-commodity>` where every `li` contains its own data.

HTML:

[image]

I started out by printing out

```
li_tags = bs4.find_all('ul', {'id': 'commodity-lister-list'})
```

which gives me the whole list which is fine. Afterthat I tried to

```
different_ids = li_tags.find_all('li')

print(different_ids)
```

but that gives me an empty value ( [] ).

What am I doing wrong and how can I be able to print out all  for there own as I can later on apply it in a for loop?

Comment: how do you get the html? Does it contain the `<li>` or are they generated by javascript?

Comment: I just edited a picture @Daniel - I totally forgot to add it at the begnning. Feel free to refresh the site! (Also it is not Javascript. Its for sure HTML since I can't all values if i print `li_tags` but not `li id` for its own

Comment: The picture does not answer my questions. Btw, don't post pictures, if you can post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.compile` to match the digits that occur in the `id`:

```
import re
li_tags = bs4.find('ul', {'id': 'commodity-lister-list'}).find_all('li', {'id':re.compile('list\-commodity-\d+')})
```

Note that HTML `id`s are unique, thus, you can use `bs4.find` and not `bs4.find_all`.

Comment: I used this function and seemes to work like I wanted but I have no idea what `'id':re.compile('list\-commodity-\d+')}` does. It would be very helpful if you would be able answer!

Comment: @WeInThis `BeautifulSoup`, you can provide a `re.compile` object in place of a string when searching for attributes. `re.compile('list\-commodity-\d+')` first matches `list-commodity-`, and then the trailing digits.

Comment: Ohhh okey! There we go! Thanksk. I got it. Did some research aswell :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `select`:

```
li_tags = bs4.select('ul[id=commodity-lister-list] li[id^=list-commodity-]')
```